# Ember.js: How to use computed property as a route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I'm pretty new to Ember.js and am building an app to pick up some Ember chops. I wanted to use a computed property in one of my models as a route but it seems something isn't working correctly. I'm using FIXTURES by the way.

What I'm trying to achieve is `/peeps/john-smith` instead of `/peeps/1`

I've got my model setup like this:

```
App.Peep = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    lastName: DS.attr('string'),
    slug: function(){
        this.get('firstName').toLowerCase() + '-' + this.get('lastName').toLowerCase();
    }.property('firstName', 'lastName')
});
```

My router setup is like this:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    this.resource('peep', { path: '/peeps/:peep_slug'});
});

App.PeepRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params){
        return this.store.find('peep', params.peep_slug);
    },

    serialize: function(model){
        return { peep_slug: model.get('slug') };
    }
});
```

When I navigate to `/peeps/john-smith` in the browser, I get this warning in my console `You made a request for a peep with id john-smith`.

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

By default it searches by `id` param, so you could either change the adapter to make it search by `slug` or try to add `id` as `Ember.computed.alias('slug')`.

Comment: how do you go about changing the adapter to have it search by `slug`?